# Writing data to large file in matlab

Tags: database, matlab

In Matlab, I need to generate and save over 8 million lines of data to a file.

I have been using fprintf, but as the file gets larger everything seems to slow down. I am not sure but I suspect fprintf is loading the whole file into memory.

Right now I have been iterating like this: calculate values, write to file, repeat.

Would it be better to say first calculate 20,000 values at a time, then write them all to file at once?

I understand data store is a good way to analyze the data, can it also be used to help write it to the file? If so, how?

Comment: Writing 8 million values one by one will definitely be slow. Calculate as many values as your memory can handle and store them in a single go.

Comment: Which format are you writing to? (`ascii`, `double`, `single`, `intx`...). It will also make a difference. `fprintf` is much faster when left with large matrices on its own (and much slower in a line by line loop). Choose the optimum format, load as much as possible in memory, then write that to file in one single call to `fprintf`.

Comment: How big is this dataset? Because 8 million double precision values is not too much I would say. `(8E6*8)/2^20=61MB` Any pc has 61MB of free memory so you can do the calculations first and then write them all at once to the datafile.